# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this Wrapper Widget

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, provider

I am following youtube tutorial for building an app using flutter. For some reason, I am getting this error. I could not find any fix for this issue.

//The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building Wrapper(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Wrapper Widget

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this Wrapper Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

Here is my code for main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(Gradebook());

class Gradebook extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Wrapper.dart

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);


    if (user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    } else{
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is where the stream provider is created.

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
  }
}
```

Here is Authenticate.dart

```
class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  bool showLogin = true;
  void toggleView() {
    setState(() => showLogin = !showLogin);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(showLogin){
      return Login(toggleView: toggleView);
    } else{
      return Register(toggleView: toggleView);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any class that extends ChangeNotifier

Comment: I am not interlay sure what you mean by that, but it was not mentioned in the video tutorials I was following. He used StreamProvider to check the state of user.uid that will come back from firebase.